# Call cloud code without logged in user Parse Server JS SDK

Tags: parse-platform, back4app

Is it possible to call a cloud function that returns objects without having a current user? The iOS and Android SDKs support anonymous users but I'm asking specifically for JavaScript.

I'd like to allow it so that anyone who visits my web app can read objects without having to sign in. I'm using Back4App.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can call a cloud code function no matter the user is logged in or not. Inside the cloud function you can check the `user` property of the `request` object to check if the user is either logged in or not. In the case that your user is not logged in and you want to query a class which requires user permission, you can use the `useMasterKey` option.

```js
Parse.Cloud.define('myFunction', async req => {
  const { user, isMaster } = req;

  if (isMater) {
    // the cloud code function was called using master key
  } else if (user) {
    // the cloud code function was called by an authenticated user
  } else {
    // the cloud code function was called without passing master key nor session token - not authenticated user
  }

  const obj = new Parse.Object('MyClass');
  await obj.save(null, { useMasterKey: true }); // No matter if the user is authenticated or not, it bypasses all required permissions - you need to know what you are doing since anyone can fire this function

  const query = new Parse.Query('MyClass');
  return query.find({ useMasterKey: true }) // No matter if the user is authenticated or not, it bypasses all required permissions - you need to know what you are doing since anyone can fire this function
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the descriptive answer Davi! Very helpful and much appreciated!